# how to maintain an boot order in regards to a usb drive CMS EFI

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, bios, uefi

I  have the same problem as this topic, [[Getting UEFI BIOS boot order consistency when attaching/removing USB?](https://superuser.com/questions/1055189/getting-uefi-bios-boot-order-consistency-when-attaching-removing-usb/1265645?noredirect=1#comment1863734_1265645])

How can I maintain a user specified boot order, when CMS/EFI will automatically delete an invalid boot entry if it is undetected?

When I enter Setup and arrange the boot order to as follows, booted with CMS:

1. USB (grub4dos)
2. Disk 1 (windows 7)
3. Disk 2 (windows 7)

It goes well and as specified as long as I keep the USB drive inserted. 
But once I remove the USB drive, reboot once without it, and reinsert the drive back, this will happen:

1. Disk 1 (windows 7)
2. Disk 2 (windows 7)
3. USB (grub4dos)

As per the link above, this is probably a bad implementation of my board's manufacturer. But I'm just hoping that there is a work around for this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "CMS" you mean the Compatibility Support Module (CSM).

In any event, I know of no true solution to the problem you're experiencing; however, there is a potential workaround: You could write an EFI program that adjusts the boot order in whatever way you like and set it as the default boot program. I don't know of any program that does this (although the `fallback.efi`/`fbx64.efi` program distributed with many Linux distributions is vaguely similar in principle -- but it works only for EFI boot loaders and wouldn't work for any arbitrary bootable USB device). Thus, you'd need to write the program yourself, which is a non-trivial task unless you're already enough of an expert that you wouldn't be asking this question.

The closest thing to a ready-to-go workaround I know of is my own [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) It's definitely overkill for your problem, but you could install it, edit `refind.conf` to enable BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode booting (via the `scanfor` option line), and set the `default_selection` line to something that would pick up your bootable USB device. Unfortunately, the exact description of the bootable USB device might vary from one device to another, so even this overkill workaround might not actually work unless you've got a limited set of devices you want to boot. OTOH, maybe it would work; you'd need to try it to find out. (The viability depends on how your firmware names bootable USB devices; if there's a consistent string that's unique to USB devices, like "USB," then this approach might work. If USB devices are named completely uniquely and you have a lot of them, rEFInd won't help much.) Using rEFInd will complicate your boot path and add some time to the boot process, even if you configure it with a timeout of 0.

Overall, then, if you're desperate enough, you might want to look into rEFInd. If this is just a minor annoyance, though, it's probably best to just live with it, unless somebody else has a better suggestion.